# Datalist element, possible to autofill multiple inputs?

Tags: html, frontend

I'm working on a datalist element to populate same fields with information about a location (Address, state, city, zip code, etc.) I noticed that Chrome can autofill multiple fields with a selection from it's pre-saved addresses that have been entered before, using an entry form one field's datalist. What I'm wondering is if it's possible for me to create options that take advantage of some browser behavior to fill multiple fields myself, or if this will need to be done programmatically. I'll post a little example snippet to try to make it more clear about what I want to do:

```html
<input type='text' name='address' list='address-suggestions' />
<datalist id='address-suggestions'>
  <option>123 Example Address Rd., New York City, NY 10001</option>
</datalist>
<input type='text' name='city' />
<input type='text' name='state' />
<input type='text' name='zip-code' />
```

My goal is to fill in all four fields with the option available in the `datalist` I'm quite confident I can do it programmatically, but given that I'm seeing Chrome do it natively, I was wondering if there was some functionality I was unaware of / had not been able to find information about elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but not all browsers behave the same.
The [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) should provide some help if your using the `autocomplete` HTML Attribute. It should allow you better control of what gets autofilled and what doesn't.

Comment: I read through the full MDN doc there on `autocomplete`, and while informative it didn't really seem to indicate anything that would help me do what I wanted to do, which is fill multiple inputs using one data list with options.